# Changing the action of an Intent

Tags: java, android

I have an Intent object and I need to change its action.

Is there any way other than calling the setAction() method?

```
Intent i = new Intent("abc");
i.setAction("def");
```

I need to change it to a new action without the setAction().

Comment: I think we need more background for Your purpose....

Answer (score 2):

> Is there any way other than calling the setAction() method?

Not really.

You can create a new `Intent` that has your desired action, then call `fillIn()` on your first `Intent`, along with `FILL_IN_ACTION` as a flag, to change the action in the first `Intent` to be the one in the second `Intent`. However, it is unclear why this would be preferable to calling `setAction()`, unless there are many more values that you want copied from the second `Intent` into the first one. And, even then, the solution might simply be to use the second `Intent` and ignore the first one.